# Проверьте правильно ли я решил?

Tags: математика, комбинаторика

Дано клетчатое игровое поле размерами n * n. На какую-то клетку игрового поля ставят фишку, которой можно совершать ходы двух типов: фишку можно передвинуть на произвольную клетку, которая имеет общую сторону с текущей клеткой, или же на произвольную клетку, которая имеет с текущей клеткой общую вершину, но не общую сторону. Два последовательных хода всегда должны быть различных типов. Найти все натуральные числа n > 1, при которых можно выбрать начальную клетку и последующие ходы так, чтобы фишка побывала на каждой клетке игрового поля ровно один раз и закончила в клетке, отличной от начальной.

**Мое решение:**

Нарезается по полоски 2*n

И есть обход одной полоски

Следующая - отраженная

Для 1 кстати не работает

Потому что там условие, что в другой клетке надо закончить

Получается можно для четных

Для 1 и 3 нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]